# Why does a manually defined Spring Data JPA delete query not trigger cascades?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have following problem: when I try to delete an entity that has following relation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pricingScheme", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
private Collection<ChargeableElement> chargeableElements;
```

with a `CrudRepository` through a provided delete method it removes the entity along with its all chargeable elements which is fine. The problem appears when I try to use my custom delete:

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM PricingScheme p WHERE p.listkeyId = :listkeyId")
void deleteByListkeyId(@Param("listkeyId") Integer listkeyId);
```

it says:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
  Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
  (`listkey`.`chargeableelements`, CONSTRAINT `FK_pox231t1sfhadv3vy7ahsc1wt` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`pricingScheme_id`) REFERENCES `pricingschemes` (`id`))
```

Why I am not allowed to do this? Does `@Query` methods do not support cascade property? I know I can `findByListkeyId(…)` first and then remove persistent entity with standard delete method, but it is inelegant. Is it possible to use a custom `@Query` method the way I tried to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but is the way JPA specifies this to work (section 4.10 - "Bulk Update and Delete Operations", JPA 2.0 specification):

> A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. It does not cascade to related entities.

If you think about it, JPA cascades are not database-level cascades but ones maintained by the `EntityManager`. Hence, the `EntityManager` needs to know about the entity instance to be deleted and its related instances. If you trigger a query, it effectively can't know about those as the persistence provider translates it into SQL and executes it. So there's no way the `EntityManager` can analyze the object graph as the execution is completely happening in the database.

A question and answer related to this topic here can be found [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533399/why-do-i-not-see-changes-issued-through-an-update-query-with-spring-data-jpa/22551997#22551997).