# Spring data testing custom repository data doesn't update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, querydsl

I am trying to write a test for custom spring data repository. I'm also using QueryDSL. 
I am new to spring-data. I use spring support for HSQL DB in testing. MySQL for dev.

Problem: I do not see updated data in tests if I use custom repository.

```
public interface AuctionRepository extends AuctionRepositoryCustom, CrudRepository<Auction, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Auction> {
// needed for spring data crud
}
```

.

```
public interface AuctionRepositoryCustom {
    long renameToBestName();
}
```

.

```
public class AuctionRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport implements AuctionRepositoryCustom {
    private static final QAuction auction = QAuction.auction;

public AuctionRepositoryImpl() {
    super(Auction.class);
}

@Override
public long renameToBestName() {
    return update(auction)
        .set(auction.name, "BestName")
        .execute();
}
}
```

**My test**
Somehow fails at last line

```
public class CustomAuctionRepositoryImplTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {
@Inject
AuctionRepository auctionRepository;

@Test
public void testDoSomething() {
    Auction auction = auctionRepository.findOne(26L);
    assertEquals("EmptyName", auction.getName());

    // test save
    auction.setName("TestingSave");
    auctionRepository.save(auction);
    Auction saveResult = auctionRepository.findOne(26L);
    assertEquals("TestingSave", saveResult.getName());

    // test custom repository
    long updatedRows = auctionRepository.renameToBestName();
    assertTrue(updatedRows > 0);
    Auction resultAuction = auctionRepository.findOne(26L);
    assertEquals("BestName", resultAuction.getName()); // FAILS expected:<[BestNam]e> but was:<[TestingSav]e>
}
}
```

I can't figure out why data doesn't update when using custom repository. If I start application in dev mode, and call renameToBestName() through controller, everything works as expected, name changes.

**Below is Test Configuration if needed**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestBeans.class, JpaConfig.class, EmbeddedDataSourceConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = IntegrationTest.class, excludeFilters = @Filter({Configuration.class}))
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {
}
```

.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
class JpaConfig {

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;
    @Value("${hibernate.isShowSQLOn}")
    private String isShowSQLOn;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("auction");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
        if ( !hbm2ddlAuto.isEmpty()) {
            jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
        }
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, isShowSQLOn);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_IMPORT_FILES_SQL_EXTRACTOR, "org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor");
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `AbstractIntegrationTest` look like?

Comment: edited and added some configuration. I will add more if needed. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Does the renaming work if you try plain old JPQL or entityManager.update?

Comment: I've tried `entityManager.refresh(resultAuction);` - test passed. That's good :-) Thanks. 
But still, why this line is needed? Maybe I'm missing some configuration?

Comment: I don't really know since I have not worked with QueryDSL that much

Comment: This case has effectively been covered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533399/why-do-i-not-see-changes-issued-through-an-update-query-with-spring-data-jpa/22551997#22551997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the update query issued through your code is defined to not evict the object potentially touched by the query from the `EntityManager`. Read more on that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533399/why-do-i-not-see-changes-issued-through-an-update-query-with-spring-data-jpa/22551997#22551997).